# How can I extract text from a span tag that doesnt have a title?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the cve from this page and a few others. Here is the link. https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/19090
However, the cve doesn't seem to have a title or anything to allow me to grab the text for it. Is there a way to do this? Here is what the html for the cve looks like.

```
<section>
    <h4 class="u-m-t-2">Reference Information</h4>
    <section>
        <p><strong>CVE
                <!-- -->:
            </strong><span><a href="/cve/CVE-2004-0804">CVE-2004-0804</a></span></p>
    </section>
    <section></section>
    <div>
        <section>
            <p><strong>CERT
                    <!-- -->:
                </strong><span><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/555304">555304</a></span></p>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

EDIT: Here is my code currently with Jack Ashtons suggestion.

```
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import urllib
import sys
import re

with open("path to file with id's") as f:
    for line in f:
        active = line
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
        reg_url = "https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/" + str(active) 
        req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 
        try:
            source = urlopen(req).read()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            if e.getcode() == 404: # check the return code  
                continue
            if e.getcode() == 502:  
                continue        
            raise

        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
        result = re.search(r"<span>(.*CVE.*)</span>", soup)
        print(result[0])
```

Comment: Without an id to search for you can write a regex expression to find the CVE. https://regex101.com/ may be helpful in figuring out a regex expression to use. There is after all section in the page with a strong title CVE so you can just grab everything after that pattern how you see fit.

Comment: @JackAshton what would be the best way to grab everything after the strong title? I'm new to bs4 and the docs are kinda confusing me

Comment: In regards to your edit and usage of regex, this won't work because regex.search expects a string. So you cannot pass soup to re.search, you should instead pass it soup.text (I think I'm not super familiar with bs4, you just need to give regex the soup object as a string of HTML)

Comment: soup.text() won't return the tags, it should be str(soup)

Answer (score 1):

With python here is a way to extract the CVE from this page. I'm not sure what the CVE is and what you want from it but since you know that "CVE" will be in the href / in the text of the tag you can search for that with regex. You can modify this to your liking this is just to get started.

```
import re

test = """
    <section>
        <h4 class="u-m-t-2">Reference Information</h4>
        <section>
        <p><strong>CVE
            <!-- -->:
            </strong><span><a href="/cve/CVE-2004-0804">CVE-2004-0804</a></span></p>
        </section>
        <section></section>
     <div>
    <section>
        <p><strong>CERT
                <!-- -->:
            </strong><span><a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/555304">555304</a></span></p>
        </section>
    </div>
  </section>
"""

result = re.search(r"<span>(.*CVE.*)</span>", test)
print(result[0])  # <a href="/cve/CVE-2004-0804">CVE-2004-0804</a>
```

Comment: It looks like when i run this i get a type error. "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" I'll post what I have as an edit

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/19090'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('a[href*="/cve/CVE"]').text )
```

Prints:

```
CVE-2004-0804
```

Or:

```
print( soup.select_one('strong:contains("CVE:") + span').text )
```

Or:

```
print( soup.select_one('h4:contains("Reference Information") + * span').text )
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = [
        f"{url[:23]+x['href']}" for x in soup.select("a[href^=\/cve\/CVE-]")]
    print(target)


main("https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/19090")
```

Output:

```
['https://www.tenable.com/cve/CVE-2004-0804']
```